# Running my code and nothing is showing

Tags: python

I fixed most of my code but the only problem I'm having is that none of the text is showing. I'm supposed to input golfer names and their scores but nothing shows up when I run the program.

```
def main():
    inGolf = open('golfers.txt', 'r')
    names = []
    scores = [] 
    for line in inGolf: 
        line_list = line.split(",")
        names.append(line_list[0]) 
        scores.append(line_list[1])

    for i in range(len(names)): 
        print ("{0:20}{1:10}".format(names[i], scores[i]))
    inGolf.close()

def w(numPlayers): 
    counter = 0
    outGolf = open('playerData.txt', 'w')
    while counter < numPlayers:
        name = raw_input("Please enter the player's name:")
        outGolf.write(name + ",")
        score = input("Please enter that player's score:")
        outGolf.write(str(score) + "\n")
        counter = counter + 1
    outGolf.close()

main()
```

Comment: There's a whole function there you never call, maybe look into that?

Comment: add some print statments to check if your entering the first `for` loop in `main()`

Comment: And while you're at it, maybe figure out why the file names are different?

Comment: Please also post the contents of the `golfers.txt` file

Comment: I think @MarkRansom may have found the root of your problem

Comment: input is from keyboard, output file is playerData.txt and then records are saved in golfers.data

Answer (score 0):

I have slightly modified this script to try it [here](https://repl.it/E1jQ/2) and it actually worked:

1. It prompts the players' names and scores by players number.
2. It saves the players file
3. It reads the players file and show scoring results.

I had to change `raw_input` to `input` as for Python3 and called the `w` function passing a number of player by user inputs:

```
def main():

    num_players = input("How many players?")
    w( int(num_players) )
    inGolf = open('golfers.txt', 'r')
    names = []
    scores = [] 
    for line in inGolf: 
        line_list = line.split(",")
        names.append(line_list[0]) 
        scores.append(line_list[1])

    for i in range(len(names)): 
        print ("{0:20}{1:10}".format(names[i], scores[i]))
    inGolf.close()


def w(numPlayers): 
    counter = 0
    outGolf = open('golfers.txt', 'w')
    while counter < numPlayers:
        name = input("Please enter the player's name:")
        outGolf.write(name + ",")
        score = input("Please enter that player's score:")
        outGolf.write(str(score) + "\n")
        counter = counter + 1
    outGolf.close()

main()
```

Comment: thank you so much! also im just trying to figure out how i would implement something like "insert the number of golfers"